# Create another div and variable onChange using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

below is a code that gets the value of the selected option and shows the php file in the div. How can I add another file and another div (secondfile) to be displayed ?

```
$('#firstresult').empty().addClass("loading")
    .load(val + '.php', { value: val }, function(){
        $("#firstresult").removeClass("loading");
    }));
$('#secondresult').empty().addClass("loading")
    .load(val + 'b.php', { value: val }, function(){
        $("#secondresult").removeClass("loading");
```

Comment: You want to be able to add as many div-php combos as the user keeps on changing the select? including showing the same php twice if the same value is selected twice ?

Comment: No. My aim is to display two different php files 1.php 1b.php (b.php) in two different divs. One for 1 and one for 1b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show a loading image, you could add a class before `load()` and remove upon `load()` complete.

**JS**

Changes to the lines that begin `$('#firstresult')` and `$('#secondresult')`.

```
$('#firstresult').empty().addClass("loading")
    .load(val + '.php', { value: val }, function(){
        $("#firstresult").removeClass("loading");
    }));
$('#secondresult').empty().addClass("loading")
    .load(val + '.php', { value: val }, function(){
        $("#secondresult").removeClass("loading");
    }));
```

**CSS**

```
.loading { height:24px; background:#fff url('loading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat; }
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you. I want to have another php file to be displayed on the second div

Comment: @Punkis: That does put them in two different `<div>`s.

Comment: @Marcel I updated my code. Can you tell me how can I add a loading image until the ajax call and display the result ?

Comment: @Punkis: My original answer was off track but I've changed it to answer your question above.

Comment: @Marcel Thank you for that. I can't get it working though. I updated my question with the whole code ( including yours )

Comment: Actually I forgot to add class="loading" and corrected your misspell at firstresult. The images is coming up, but not the text.

Answer (score 0):

Create / Append div in results div as child and load content from php script to it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#termid').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('results').append('<div id="result' + val '"></div>');
    $('#result' + val).load(val + '.php',
    {
        value: val
    });
  });
});
```

not tested

Comment: Thanks for it. My aim is to display two different php files 1.php 1b.php (b.php) in two different divs. One for 1 and one for 1b.